# counting specific elements in array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of `[2,3,4,3,4,5,6,3]` now I want to know how many 3's are there in an array. Is there any short cut to do it rather than going through the loop and checking each element?

Comment: What do you mean by shortcut? performant way?

Comment: Saeed's point is very valid.  "short cut" by way of concise source code, or shortcut for performance?  For performance, obviously you might get benefits from parallel searches in different parts of a very large array.  But each thread still has to do element by element comparison.  There are almost certainly faster assembly langauge commands than the naive compilation of a loop doing comparisons - your compiler might or might not use them - but there's nothing directly specifiable in C++.

Comment: I mean in terms of no. of lines of code!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `std::count` from `<algorithm>`:

```
std::count(array.begin(), array.end(), 3)
// or if it's a raw array: std::count(array, array + NUM_OF_ELEMENTS, 3)
// or the most generic solution (std::{begin,end} are from C++11):
std::count(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 3)
```